# How do you pass Javascript touch events to Objective-C UIWebView native code?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview, touchesbegan, uiwebviewdelegate

I am aware that the UIWebView contains a method that it calls before a link loads, namely webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:.

Using this, native code in the UIWebView delegate can intercept load requests and decide what to do about them, and this affords us a method of communication between a UIWebView and the JavaScript running within it.

However, this seems like a poor solution when trying to pass information such as touch events or current touch position. Should we fake a link load for every touch event and pass the information that way? This seems slow and hack-ish. What is a better way to do this?